# Accessing Smartsheet Oauth in html page

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

I have asked in my post earlier what url / redirect url I should use here:
[how to request auth code from Smartsheet via Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016000/how-to-request-auth-code-from-smartsheet-via-postman)
An user suggested me to ngrok, it gave me a temporary website when I set the http to 80. However, I noticed the forwarding website given is different every time I type

```
./ngrok http 80
```

Here are my questions:

1. if the forwarding website is different , how am I able to get a 'allow access' page as I don't know what app url and redirect url I should put for my Smartsheet.
2. I tried to request the website by typing
   ./ngrok http80
   It gave me a forwarding , so I type the website as my app url, and /callback as the redirect url, I still don't get the 'allow access' page
   the Smartsheet documentation asks me to type in the following

   https://app.smartsheet.com/b/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=dheu3dmkd32fhxme&scope=READ_SHEETS%20WRITE_SHEETS&state=MY_STATE

   I tried to use postman for the command above, it does not show me any error nor showing the 'allow access' page.
   I am trying to get the 'allow access' page to work in my html file, but I am not sure what code I should put.

I am novice to smarsheet API, any explanation in detail will be appreciated. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the ngrok docs you can set a [custom subdomain](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-subdomain) each time you launch ngrok. This way you can have the same URL for repeated use.
This way you could have a command to run ngrok look like this:
`ngrok http -subdomain=testsmartsheetoauth 80`
Your URL would look like this:
`http://testsmartsheetoauth.ngrok.io`
And your callback could be set to this:
`http://testsmartsheetoauth.ngrok.io/callback`
This should give you the persistent URLs you need that your app could use for the OAuth flow.